# I am doing a case-control study and I want to match cases to controls in a 1:5 ratio, by a number of important variables. However, When

Tags: r, duplicates, matching

I am doing a case-control study and I want to match cases to controls in a 1:5 ratio, by a number of important variables. However, when I try do this, I get a number of duplicate controls in my data set. Does anyone know how to remove duplicates in r while running through the for loop?

- case=case data set
- con= control data set

So far my code looks like this:

```
out <- NULL
for (i in 1: length(case[,5]) ){
g <-case$Sex[i]
y <-case$Age[i]


x <- sample((which(con$Sex==g & con$Age>=y-1 & con$Age<=y+1)), size=5 )
out <- c(out, x)
if (duplicated(out)=="TRUE")
    i=i-1;
    out = out(size(out)-1,);
end
}
```

But the part trying to remove duplicates is wrong and I am not sure how to fix it, Any suggestions?

Comment: To remove duplicated values typically you would use `unique()`.

Comment: please provide a reproducible example of your in and output, e.g. using dput()`

Comment: I would use `out <- c(out, x); out <- out[!duplicated(out)]`. Also what version of `sample` are you using? There is one for `dplyr` and one for base R?

Comment: @akash87 with no `dplyr` in the question it's pretty safe to assume the `base` version. Also the `dplyr` functions are `sample_n`, `sample_group`, and `sample_frac`, not just `sample`.

Comment: Thank very much @akash87, that worked.